# What is the correct way to make \setmainfont take effect?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[BoldItalicFont={Times New Roman}]{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

    1. This is normal as expected.

    \textit{2. This is in italic as expected.}
    
    \textbf{3. This is in bold as expected.}
    
    \textit{\textbf{4. This is NOT in italic and bold as expected.}}

    \textbf{\textit{5. This is NOT in bold and italic as expected.}}

\end{document}
```

The output is as below:

[image]

What is the correct way to make `\setmainfont[BoldItalicFont={Times New Roman}]{DejaVu Sans}` take effect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Technical answer:**
You are telling `fontspec` that whenever a bold italic font is requested, it should use *upright regular* Times New Roman.
You should write `BoldItalicFont={Times New Roman Bold Italic}` instead.

**Stylish comment:**
Using both bold and italic is generally considered a bad practice (and, in my opinion, Times New Roman Bold Italic is absolutely ugly). It also matches very poorly Dejavu Sans, so please consider a different serif/sans serif font couple.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[BoldItalicFont={Times New Roman Bold Italic}]{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}
    1. This is normal as expected.
    \textit{2. This is in italic as expected.}
    \textbf{3. This is in bold as expected.}
    \textit{\textbf{4. This is in italic and bold as expected.}}
    \textbf{\textit{5. This is in bold and italic as expected.}}
\end{document}
```

[image: File preview]